# sort command (MacOS terminal) gives inconsistent results

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

The man page for sort says

> ```
>  -u, --unique
>         Unique keys.  Suppress all lines that have a key that is equal to
>         an already processed one.
> ```

But I am getting behavior that I just don't understand. When I sort on column #1, -u doesn't seem to work, when I sort on column #2, it sort of works, and it works correctly when I sort on column #3. Obviously, either it is broken or I am confused. (Probably the latter).

```
$ cat tosort.txt
1   A   a
3   A   a
1   B   a
2   B   b
3   B   a
$ cat -t tosort.txt
1^IA^Ia
3^IA^Ia
1^IB^Ia
2^IB^Ib
3^IB^Ia
$ sort tosort.txt -t$'\t' -k 1 -u
1   A   a
1   B   a
2   B   b
3   A   a
3   B   a
$ sort tosort.txt -t$'\t' -k 2 -u
1   A   a
1   B   a
2   B   b
$ sort tosort.txt -t$'\t' -k 3 -u
1   A   a
2   B   b
$
```

This is a 5 line file with three columns, separated by tabs. When I sort and find unique keys for column #1, it returns all lines, sorted by column #1, even though there are only 3 unique keys. When I sort and find unique keys for column #2, it returns 3 lines sorted by column #2, even though there are only 2 unique keys. When I sort and find unique keys for column #3, it returns 2 lines, sorted, as expected.

Comment: Just `-k1` means the key *starts* in column 1, but falls back to look at columns 2 and 3. You need `-k1,1` to say don't look at the other columns at all. This is a common FAQ.